# titanium 3.2.2 tabGroup with navigationGroup

Tags: ios, tabs, uinavigationcontroller, titanium

I've just updated one of my titanium projects from v. 3.1.3 to 3.2.2 and I'm experiencing a strange behaviour: while trying to insert an iOS navigationGroup(now called navigationWindow) inside a tabGroup i get an extra title bar.

//root view controller
http://imgur.com/MqibvFf

//pushed window
https://i.stack.imgur.com/orbQz.jpg

Here is the code i'm using:

```
var navControllerCareer = Titanium.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
        window:career, //it's a window
        navBarHidden: true,
        fullscreen: true
    });

var career_tab = Ti.UI.createTab({
    title: 'CARRIERA',
    font:{
        fontSize:'13dp',
        fontWeight:'bold'
      },
    deselectedBackgroundColor:'#9e9e9e',
    selectedBackgroundColor:'#6d6d6d',
    window: navControllerCareer,
    navBarHidden: true,
    fullscreen: true
});
```

Before updating to 3.2.2 it worked normally.
Is the combined use of tabgroup + navgroup no longer supported?

Comment: Why you are using navWindow when you could use the nav of tabBar?

Comment: Does it provide the same behaviour of the classic navController? I wasn't aware there is a navWindow available inside a tabGroup.

Can you link me a link or a snipper to see how to use it? 

Anyway i'm having the same problem even when i'm using a simple navWindow without tabs.
http://imgur.com/GgWclLN

Comment: Plz share your code of other files too that are related

Comment: Ok, I were wrong: using only a navController works correctly, i mistyped a require and i was instantiating 2 navGroups one inside the other.
My original question still remains: how should i use a the tabgroup navigation controller to correcty push and pop every new window?